# Merge 2 Arrays on second level with different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge two arrays on the second level with different key names but the same amount of keys.

- usera=102
- userb=103

My desired output would be array 3.

I have tried a lots of variations to get this together.

My best attempt was something like the following but it destroyed my key names:

```
$results = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key => $array)
{
  foreach($array as $user => $value)
   {
    $results[$user]['name'] = $value;   
   }
}

foreach($arr2 as $key => $array)
{   
  foreach($array as $user => $value)
   {
    $results[$user]['name2'] = $value;
   } 
}
```

**Array 1 :**

```
     Array
        (
            [usera] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => usera
                            [duration_s] => 15
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => usera
                            [duration_s] => 9
                        )
                )
            [userb] => Array
                (
                   [2] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => userb
                            [duration_s] => 21  
                        )

                   [3] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => userb
                            [duration_s] => 19
                        )
                )

        )
```

**Array 2:**

```
 Array
            (
                [102] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [user] => 102
                                [duration_s2] => 54
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [user] => 102
                                [duration_s2] => 378
                            )
                    )
                [103] => Array
                    (
                       [2] => Array
                            (
                                [usernr] => 103
                                [duration_s2] => 299
                            )

                       [3] => Array
                            (
                                [usernr] => 103
                                [duration_s2] => 110
                            )
                    )

            )
```

**Array 3:**

```
 Array
    (
        [usera] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [user] => usera
                        [duration_s] => 15
                        [usernr] => 102
                        [duration_s2] => 54
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [user] => usera
                        [duration_s] => 9
                        [usernr] => 102
                        [duration_s2] => 378
                    )
            )
        [userb] => Array
            (
               [2] => Array
                    (
                        [user] => userb
                        [duration_s] => 21  
                        [usernr] => 103
                        [duration_s2] => 299
                    )

               [3] => Array
                    (
                        [user] => userb
                        [duration_s] => 19
                        [usernr => 103
                        [duration_s2] => 110
                    )
            )

    )
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at how you create the original 2 arrays. Make the amendment there so you create the required array as part of that process

Comment: Thank you for the response. The Arrays come from 2 separate database hosts, so i am not able to join them together.

Comment: Do we assume that the array indexes that make no logical sence are just typo's? Or do `Userb`'s sub arrays really contain the indexes `[2] & [3]` and not `[0] & [1]`

Comment: No, they really contain the indexes 2 and 3. I am really new to programming. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code using `array_values()` :

```
<?php
$array1 = [
  'usera' => [
                0=> ['user' => 'usera','duration_s' => 15],
                1=> ['user' => 'usera','duration_s' => 9],
            ],
  'userb' => [
                2=> ['user' => 'usera','duration_s' => 15],
                3=> ['user' => 'usera','duration_s' => 9],
            ],

   ];

$array2 = [
  102 => [
     0=> ['usernr' => 102,'duration_s2' => 54],
     1=> ['usernr' => 102,'duration_s2' => 378]
  ],
 103 => [
    2=> ['usernr' => 103,'duration_s2' => 299],
    3=> ['usernr' => 103,'duration_s2' => 110]
 ],

];


$array2 = array_values($array2);
$array1 = array_values($array1);

foreach($array1 as $index=>$ar1){
 foreach ($ar1 as $index2=>$ar2){
     $array1[$index][$index2] = array_merge($ar2,$array2[$index][$index2]);
 }
}


print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Perfect.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To merge the array you can also do the following :

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) { // changing the indexing of second array
    $arr3[$index] = $value;
    $index++;
}

$results = array();

$count = 0;
foreach ($arr1 as $index => $value) { // merging two array

    $total = 0;
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $merge_value = array_merge($val,$arr3[$count][$total]);
        $results[$index][$total] = $merge_value;
        $total++;
    }
    $count++;
}
print_r($results);
```

In this result your indexing will not lost.

Comment: This would be even better but the results of the second users sub arrays are empty if i am not mistaken.

Comment: For me the total variable needs to be declared above the second foreach statement to get the desired result.